# How to import or add other classes from an external folder?

Tags: java

I have four classes in the operators package (e:\operators). Also I have another package named main (e:\project\main). In the main package I have an interface named Operator.

My 4 classes implement this interface. But I don't know how to import packages from another folder(main and operators are in different folders). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add the steps you used for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the operators directory to your classpath in whatever IDE you're using, then import them in your code like you would any other package.

Comment: I do this  .I compile the code like so : javac -cp .;E:\project\main;  *.java

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If yes, what IDE? I don't use the command line to compile Java, but I don't see you mention the operators directory in that command.

Comment: I don't use an IDE  . dot(.) shows the current directory

Comment: I don't know if your command is correct or not, but assuming it is, did you try importing the classes in your code? If it doesn't work I would suggest double checking your command to make sure the operators directory is being added to the classpath properly.

Answer (score 0):

A proper answer for this question can be given if u had mentioned which IDE you are using.

Classes normally come as files in the file Explorer view. The easiest way is to copy the file (right click + copy) and go to your IDE and paste it in the relevant package.

Depending on the IDE, it will automatically add this class to your new project. (some IDE s change the Xml files and other relevant grade components accordingly.)

Please note :
The copying and pasting of files should be of the same language. There won't be any issues with copying. But it will not function if you use different language formats.

Answer (score 0):

While specifying the java classpath (-cp) specify the till directory where the package exists.

If you are importing `import main.operator.*` you should only use `javac -cp .;E:\project\ *.java` (not "E:\project\main") since main package is in this directory. You will also need to specify the same classpath when executing as well.

```
javac -cp .;E:\project\ *.java
java -cp .;E:\project\ <class_name>
```

Remember java package hierarchy is also shown in directory structure. That is if you use `import package1.package2.some_class` then the java looks for the directory structure `package1/package2/some_class.class` in the given classpath directories.